# Chinese input with Stroke 5

Tags: debian, input-method, fcitx

I need to use input Chinese characters on my Debian Sid laptop. I would like to use the "Stroke 5" method.

I've installed Fcitx and selected the "Stroke5" input method in the Fcitx configuration wizard, but I'm not able to trigger the Fcitx suggestions window while typing.

[image: Fcitx configuration window]

*Questions:*

1. Do you know of any guide to get started with Chinese input on Debian?
2. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Move it to the top using `^`.

Comment: "Do you know of any guide to get started with Chinese input on Debian?" https://wiki.debian.org/gnome-chinese-input

Comment: @arochester I've not been able to make it work using this guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Fcitx, SCIM and IBus. IBus was the only one that worked:

```
apt-get install ibus ibus-table-stroke5
im-config
ibus-setup
ibus restart
```